# `md5sum -c` won't work with Apache's MD5 file format

Tags: apache, md5sum

**Let me take you on a journey..**

I'm trying to download and verify Apache Spark (http://www.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.0/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz) via MD5 on a fresh Debian (Jessie) machine.

The `md5sum` script already existed on that machine without me needing to do anything.

As such I continue by downloading the MD5 checksum (http://www.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.0/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.md5) to the same directory as the downloaded Spark, and then I execute:

```
md5sum -c spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.md5
```

This fails with:

```
md5sum: spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.md5: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
```

And so I check the contents via `cat spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.md5`:

```
spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz: 62 4B 16 1F 67 70 A6 E0  E0 0E 57 16 AF D0 EA 0B
```

That's the whole file. Looks decent to me - maybe the Spark download was actually bad? Before taking that assumption I'll first see what the MD5 is now via `md5sum spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`:

```
624b161f6770a6e0e00e5716afd0ea0b  spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz
```

Hmm, that's a completely different format - but if you look hard enough you'll notice that the numbers and letters are actually the same (except lowercase and without spaces). It looks like the `md5sum` that comes with Debian is following a different standard.

Maybe there's another way I can run this command? Lets try `md5sum --help`:

```
Usage: md5sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Print or check MD5 (128-bit) checksums.
With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -b, --binary         read in binary mode
  -c, --check          read MD5 sums from the FILEs and check them
      --tag            create a BSD-style checksum
  -t, --text           read in text mode (default)

The following four options are useful only when verifying checksums:
      --quiet          don't print OK for each successfully verified file
      --status         don't output anything, status code shows success
      --strict         exit non-zero for improperly formatted checksum lines
  -w, --warn           warn about improperly formatted checksum lines

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The sums are computed as described in RFC 1321.  When checking, the input
should be a former output of this program.  The default mode is to print
a line with checksum, a character indicating input mode ('*' for binary,
space for text), and name for each FILE.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Report md5sum translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/md5sum>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) md5sum invocation'
```

Okay, `--tag` seems to change the format. Lets try `md5sum --tag spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`:

```
MD5 (spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz) = 624b161f6770a6e0e00e5716afd0ea0b
```

Indeed, that is a different format, but still not the right one.. So I look to the instructions on the [Apache Download Mirrors](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-1.6.0/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz) page and find the following text:

> Alternatively, you can verify the MD5 hash on the file. A unix program called `md5` or `md5sum` is included in many unix distributions. It is also available as part of [GNU Textutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/textutils/textutils.html)...

So I follow that link and find that Textutils was merged to Coreutils in 2003 - so I actually want the `md5sum` from Coreutils then. However you can see at the bottom of the `md5sum --help` dump that it's already from Coreutils.

That might mean that my Coreutils are out of date. So I'll `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade coreutils`, but then I found out that:

```
Calculating upgrade... coreutils is already the newest version.
```

That's a dead end then.. but wait a moment, they said "`md5` or `md5sum`"! Lets check out that lead.

The `md5` script doesn't exist yet, so I'll try `apt-get install md5`:

```
E: Unable to locate package md5
```

And now I'm lost, and so turn to Google and then StackOverflow for help.. Now here I am.

**So what's with the two different MD5 file formats and how can I deal with this issue (and finally verify my Apache Spark)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `gpg --print-md md5 spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz` should match the .md5 file's content.

There were problems with the format of the md5/sha files 'cause the script that builds the spark release uses `gpg --print-md md5` to create the signature files. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5308

Comment: Ahh, fascinating.. why do they tell us to use coreutil's `md5sum` then (rhetorical question). An actual question though: what's the right way to emulate the `-c` in `md5sum -c` using this `gpg` script? The "naive" way would be to simply diff the files and hope nothing's different - is there a better way? Also, from the comments on that issue it's apparent that it was changed to `md5`/`md5sum` (with a merged pull request, explaining why they tell us to use one of them) - but why do we still have the `gpg` formatted data coming out then?

Comment: The bug was reported for some maven incompatibility so they only modified how those signature files were created. `gpg` is still used to create the final package' signature.

Comment: Roger, so how would you check the downloaded file then?

Comment: You'll have to go with something like `gpg --print-md MD5 spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz | diff - spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.md5` cause I don't think there's an automatic way to do this. You can always download the `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.asc` file and do something like `gpg --verify spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz.asc spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz` after getting the public key